# Asking about legal scenarios

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Say I'm building the grounds for a story, but I'm concerned with the specific legal arguments that would revolve a given hypothetical situation.

I could ask a legal question on law.stackexchange, but I wouldn't see any sense on making it country-specific. Hence it would likely be closed.

I would like answers that explain what readers would believe to be a realistic law system or particular adjudication, rather than nailing what would actually happen on a pre-determined real place. Obviously, I'm not seeking legal advice.

To avoid having an open-ended questions, I could give a few scenarios like "judge orders A or B", hence the objective question is under what argument would a judge elaborate such ruling.

> Is such a question on-topic on this site?

From what the help center says, it seems like it doesn't, unless we consider it about "culture" (which I think is not). Also, because the world is meant to be a  little generic current time big city, is not like a lot of context makes sense for a reality check question.

Comment: Checking out well received questions under the [tag:law] tag would be a good start for seeing the best way to make this work.

Comment: If you don't see any sense in making it country-specific just look at how the laws vary from country to country and from state to state. You have the defend your castle thingy in Texas. Guns are a right in America. But Guns are extremely prohibited in other parts of the world. Depending on the jurisdiction, the outcome will vary from Not Guilty to Murder and illegal possession of firearms. If you are unsure about a country, simply use your current country/location or one that best represents your world/story (e.g. America/Cali). Because those laws are the ones that make more sense to you.

Answer (score 8):

We have questions about legal systems, so your question *can* be on-topic.  You'll need to be careful to provide enough information for people to answer somewhat objectively; opinion polls aren't a good fit for the format.  If you sufficiently specify the axioms of your question, we should be able to reason from those to new outcomes.

Specifying a whole legal system is likely to be a large project, but your system is probably based on something.  Perhaps you can describe your system as based on X but with variations A, B, and C.  If you can illustrate some of the practical differences of those variations up front, so much the better -- it shows that you've done some thinking about it already and A, B, and C *probably* aren't mutually incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

It's totally okay to ask a question on Law Stack Exchange without specifying a country.

However, what you do need to specify is the legal system you're looking at: either you know the structure and want to know the kind of laws used to handle your issue there, or you know the laws handling your issue and want to know the kind of structure that would be using them.